# Find the character of a string by inputting the position in c

Tags: c

Hi I know that there are alot of examples where you input a character to and output the position of the character. But how do you do it the other way around where you input the position and output the character ?

- input string: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
- input position: 0
- output: The character in position 0 is 'a'

Do I use `atoi`?

```
int main(void) {

char line[SIZE];
int position;

// int character = getchar(); //get string
scanf("%d\n", &position); //get position
int i = 0;
while(fgets(line, SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
    if(line[i] == position) { 
       printf("The character in postion %d is '%c'\n", position,line[i]);   
        //flag = TRUE;
   // }
    i++;
}       

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `line[i] == position`: comparing a char with an integer? what is position??

Comment: position is a number you enter for example like abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0
and I want to print out 'a'

Comment: then what's wrong with `line[position]` ?

Comment: it does not run

Comment: `line[position]` works but if position is bigger than line length you could have surprises. Test `strlen(line)` first. your question is very unclear

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and show one or two examples of input and expected output.

Comment: sorry guys i edited the input and output

Answer (score 1):

```
while(fgets(line, SIZE, stdin) != NULL) 

  {

     line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0'; // as fgets append '\n' before '\0', replacing '\n' with '\0'
     if(strlen(line) > position)
     {   
           printf("The character in postion %d is '%c'\n", position,line[position]); 
     }   
     else
     {   
        printf("invalid position\n");
     }   

}
```

Comment: Note: `line[strlen(line)-1]` is a problem should the evil user enter first a null character in the line input.  Alternative `line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {    
  char line[SIZE];
  int position;

  scanf("%d", &position); //get position
  getchar();   // absorb \n from scanf (yes scanf is somewhat odd)

  while (fgets(line, SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
      printf("The character in postion %d is '%c'\n", position, line[position]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

No out of range check whatsoever is done here for brevity

**Example of execution:**

```
1
abc
The character in postion 1 is 'b'
Hello
The character in postion 1 is 'e'
TEST
The character in postion 1 is 'E'
```

**This small example may help too:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(void) {
  char line[SIZE];

  fgets(line, SIZE, stdin);
  for (int i = 0; line[i] != 0; i++)
  {
    printf("The character in postion %d is '%c'\n", i, line[i]);
  }
}
```

No error checks done either for brevity.